# Mailcow SOGO with Nginx login errors with a 502

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx Proxy Manager server sitting in front of the mailcow Nginx server. Everything works fine ... the Sogo page loads. But when I try to login it issues a 502... logs on all servers don't really point to any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following to your Custom Nginx Configuration found in the advanced tab**

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://site.you.want:9007/;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size 0;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 64 512k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: For anyone lookin for explaination, see here: https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized/issues/4537 and here https://docs.mailcow.email/post_installation/firststeps-rp/#nginx . Actually the following lines should fix the isseu:

`proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 64 512k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
`